# Facebook campaings structure changes

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I'm using bulk import to Power Editor to create campaigns. How can I know, how my excel file should look like, when campaign structure changes ike it is said in these news: http://www.jonloomer.com/2014/08/19/new-facebook-campaign-structure/

Answer (score 1):

There will be two extra columns "Targeting Level" and "Pricing Level" which determine if those settings live at ad or ad set level. If you don't include these columns, Power Editor will try to do it's best to guess the level correctly, i.e. if you're updating existing ad/ad set, it will keep targeting/pricing where it is; if you're creating new ad/ad set, it will set targeting/pricing at ad set level - if you already have access to the migration.

Good practice is to export the data after your ad account is migrated and use that spreadsheet for upload.